# CoffeeScript: Assigning values to object

Tags: coffeescript

Let´s say I have following object:

```
dict = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

following works perfectly:

```
{a, b} = dict
// -> a = 1
// -> b = 2
```

Now I want to manipulate those numbers and write it back to the object and clearly following line does not work:

```
// some manipulations
dict = {a, b}
```

Obviously I have overwritten the `dict` object. What I essentially wanted to do is assign `dict.a = a` and `dict.b = b` with `dict.c` staying as it is.

**Is it possible to achieve my goal with some sort of a short notation?**

Comment: Use an `extend(...)` style function, like this one: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract a slice of an object into separate local variables using:

```
{a, b} = dict
```

but there's no way to assign to a slice of an object, i.e. you can't do things like this:

```
dict{a, b} = [ x, y ]
```

as a shortcut for

```
dict.a = x
dict.b = y
```

You can't even extract an object slice into a new object with things like this:

```
obj = dict{a, b}
```

you have to do it in two steps:

```
{ a, b } = dict
obj      = { a, b }
```

[Destructured assignments](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) work well to pull things out of objects but they're not that useful for putting things back into objects. I think the closest you can get is to use a destructured array assignment:

```
[ dict.a, dict.b ] = [ a, b ]
```

If you're working with several keys, then you could put the keys in an array and do the slicing and merging with loops (possibly wrapped in helper functions):

```
slice = (obj, keys...) ->
    s = { }
    s[k] = obj[k] for k in keys
    s

merge = (dest, src) ->
    dest[k] = src[k] for k of src
    return

keys = [ 'a', 'b' ]
dict = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
s = slice(dict, keys...)
s.a += 6
s.b += 6
merge(dict, s)
# dict is now { a: 7, b: 8, c: 3 }
```

Or just use the Underscore, jQuery, ... utility functions.

Answer (score 1):

In pure coffeescript:

```
extend = (a, others...) ->
  for o in others
    a[key] = val for key, val of o
  a

dict = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
{a, b} = dict

a = 5
b = 8

extend dict, {a, b}

console.log dict
#dict = { a: 5, b: 8, c: 3 }
```

Comment: Considiring that I am not using any framework and to not attend to write any helper function, the short answer to my original question is no?

Comment: Probably, I am not aware of another way without declaring your function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using underscore.js, I would do this:

```
dict = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
{a, b} = dict
...
dict = _.extend dict, {a:a, b:b}
```

As asawyer points out, there's a similar extend function in jQuery too.

Comment: `_.extend` modifies its first argument so you don't need the assignment.

Comment: Or better yet: [`_.extend dict, {a, b}`](http://coffeescript.org/#try:_.extend%20dict%2C%20%7Ba%2C%20b%7D). Also, `_.extend` will modify the `dict` object itself, so there's no need to re-assign it :) (edit: it seems mu is too short beat me to it hehe)

Comment: Considiring that I am not using any framework and to not attend to write any helper function, the short answer to my original question is no?

Comment: @Amberlamps: I think the short answer is *no*, the long rambling answer is below (or above depending on voting).